# Get filepath of image on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, filepath

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application and have some pictures already in it which are populated into a listbox like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="Control" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="10">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="10"/>
              </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The ViewModel is simple at the momment

```
public class MainPageViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Picture> _pictures;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Pictures = new ObservableCollection<Picture>
            {
                new Picture
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/Pictures/1.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
                    }
                 //Add more images here
            };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get { return _pictures; }
        set
        {
            _pictures = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Pictures);
        }
    }
}
```

I now want that by tapping on an image the user gets options for sharing

```
 void ShowShareMediaTask(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
 {
      ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
      shareMediaTask.FilePath = //something needs to go here
      shareMediaTask.Show();
 }
```

Any ideas how I can get the physical (full) path of this image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are referencing images stored in the application folder (in the project) so the `ShareMediaTask` can't access it.

The `ShareMediaTask` requires the photo to be in the Media Library.

What you need to do is save the photo the the Media Library and then call the `ShareMediaTask` with the path of the saved image (don't forget to add the `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;` to have access to the `GetPath()` extension method).

```
var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
shareMediaTask.FilePath = picture.GetPath(); // requires using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;
shareMediaTask.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out which references are required. It's a shame that VS can't resolve them automatically as it does with almost anything else

Answer (score 0):

yes... you can generate tap event of list box follow below code

```
private void Control_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {


        ObservableCollection<Picture> pictureobj=new ObservableCollection<Picture>();
        ListBox lst = (ListBox)sender;
        int i = lst.SelectedIndex;
        if (lst.SelectedValue == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Pictures obj = (Pictures)lst.SelectedValue;
           ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
           shareMediaTask.FilePath = obj.yoursetterimagepath
           shareMediaTask.Show();

        }
    }
```

hope it will help you

Comment: The problem here is that I have the relative path but I need to have a full path for the shareMediTask to work. That's why (I guess) I have to save it first and then share it around

Comment: so you suppose to use UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute path